# X button with circle in iPhone Controls

Tags: iphone, uibutton

You know that grey circle with white "X" in it in textboxes for iPhone controls that is used to delete the current line of text, is that available as an icon somewhere?  I'd like to put that icon along with the words "Clear" into a UIButton but not sure if that is availalbe.  Thanks.

Comment: Even though we are talking about a small icon, be aware of possible copyrights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not part of the public API, you'd have to use your own custom image. Which could simply mean using an editor to slice it out of a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's website uses a reset icon in its search field that you could [download](http://images.apple.com/global/nav/images/globalsearch_reset.gif). Not sure how well it will work with the iPhone 4 display PPI though. (It doesn't seem to appear when I visit the site with an iPhone.)

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for, he is searching for the buttons in UITextView